# How to specify flake8 config files when using nvie/vim-flake8 plugin in vim?

Tags: python, vim, flake8

### System Info

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

$ flake8 --version
4.0.1 (mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.8.0, pyflakes: 2.4.0) CPython 3.7.1 on
Linux
```

---

Hi

**Context/Background:**

I am using flake8 for syntax checking in vim. To do this in my vimrc I have the following:

```
Plugin 'Vundle/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'

[other plugins]
```

I installed the plugins using:

```
:PluginInstall
```

And because I do not have permissions for the standard install paths I installed flake8 in to a local directory:

```
pip install --target=/home/user/python/local-packages flake8
```

This all seems to work fine - I can open a python file in vim, press  and get a list of errors in a window below.

However I'd like to be able to ignore some errors (i.e do the equivalent to calling flake8 with --extend-ignore) and am struggling to get this to work.

Initially I thought I needed to add the following to the vim file:

```
let g:flake8_ignore="W391"
```

But when I do this it comes up with the following error:

```
Flake8 found issues
g:flake8_ignore has been deprecated in favour of flake8 config files
http://flake8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html
```

The flake8 documention says you can use --extend-ignore on the command line and indeed that works,
but trying to use it in vim as I did above does not seem to work and the error insinuates that when using vim you need to use the flake configuration file.

However I cannot get the configuration file to work. The configuration documentation for flake8 states:

> In the top-level flake8 directory (which contains docs, flake8, and
> tests) there’s also tox.ini and setup.cfg files. In our case, we keep
> our Flake8 configuration in tox.ini.

In the local area where I installed flake8 using the above pip command (/home/user/python/local-packages) flake8 directory was created and that seems to be where the flake8 files are, but there is no tests or docs directory or tox.ini file, so I am not entirely sure where the 'top level directory' is.

When I create a tox.ini in my local flake8 directory that looks like:

```
[flake8]
ignore = W391
```

then run flake8 on my file, I get:

> $ flake8 getsmemvalues.py getsmemvalues.py:412:1: W391 blank line at
> end of file

So that config file is not being picked up.
However running:

```
$ flake8 --config=/home/user/python/local-packages/flake8/tox.ini getsmemvalues.py
```

Gives:

```
getsmemvalues.py:107:58: E226 missing whitespace around arithmetic operator
```

Here it looks like it is now using my config file (W391 error is not reported), but E226 is reported where it wasn't before, so under normal circumstances it must be picking up a default config file from somewhere, but I have no idea where (clearly not /home/user/python/local-packages/flake8).

Also when I run

```
$ flake8 --append-config=/home/user/python/local-packages/flake8/tox.ini getsmemvalues.py
```

I still get the E226 errors reported:

```
getsmemvalues.py:107:58: E226 missing whitespace around arithmetic operator**strong text**
```

So it looks like the 'ignore' statement in my local config file completely overrides any ignore statement in the default config file.

**My questions are:**

1. Does anyone know how I can find out where flake8 is getting it's default config file from ? Is there a command I can use to list the config files it is using ?
2. Does anyone know how I can tell the vim flake plugin to use a non-default config file (i.e specify the equivalent of --config=)
   I've tried using something like:

   let g:flake8_config="/home/user/python/local-packages/flake8/tox.ini"

   but while I do not get any errors using this it does not seem to pick up that config file.
   In  .vim/bundle/vim-flake8/README.mdown it says:

> 1.6: Deprecated configuring flake8 options through Vim settings.  Instead,
> advise users to use the `~/.config/flake8` config file.

But using this as a config file also does not work.

3. Is there a way in the config file to append to the ignore list already specified by the default config file ?

Answer (score 3):

from [configuring flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#configuration-locations)

> Flake8 supports storing its configuration **in your project** in one of setup.cfg, tox.ini, or .flake8.

(emphasis mine) -- put your configuration file inside your project and flake8 will discover it

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer

Comment: Ah Sorry I mis-read this and interpreted it as being the directory where flake was installed. The file I was testing was not in the same directory structure as where flake is installed.

Comment: So you have to have a separate config file for each projects area ? There is no place where it can be picked up globally ? (Having a a config file locally does work both from the command line and in vim)

Comment: correct, a project's linting settings should be versioned with the project itself

Comment: As far as defaults go does flake use a default config file ? And if so is there a command to show where it is getting it from or to print out what is in it? Or are these hard coded ? Also referring to question 3 is there a way of appending to the existing default ignore list in the custom config file ? Or do you always need to repeat the default list in the local config ?

Comment: there is no "default config", no

Comment: different questions should be separate q&a on stack overflow, also if you click through the docs and read the options it answers your question

Comment: OK. Thank you for your help.